# Keep trace of downloaded resources via HTTP with Python requests module

Tags: http, browser, python-requests, httprequest

I visit *en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello* while keeping open Chrome console: in *Network* tab I can check HTTP requests' content: the first one to be called is:

```
GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello -> 200
```

then, a lot of others HTTP requests are handled: the Wikipedia logo *.png*, some CSS, scripts and others file are downloaded to my browser and together they render the actual page of Wikipedia.

With `requests`, I want to do the same thing: a simple

```
requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello")
```

will return me the HTML document of Hello page, but no other resource will be downloaded.

I want to keep trace of the number of connections opened to render a page and what elements are downloaded; the GET request above will not return images, CSS or scripts.

I think I'm missing something important: who does know what are all the necessary resources required to completely load a web page?

I'm asking this because I want (with `requests`) know what resources are downloaded and how many connections did it take to get them.

I think the server is the one who knows what a page needs to be loaded, so the server should tell this information to the client, but I'm missing where: I did not find anything in HTTP request headers.

I need this list/dictionary/JSON/whatever of resources necessary to fully render a page, so I can manually do it with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High five myself XD

The other required resources are (listed) in the first downloaded resource: the HTML document.
I'm going to parse it (`BeautifulSoup4`) and get what I need (`<link rel=... href=... />`), this should get me the number of downloads and resources the page needs.

As for the number of connections, I read about [*HTTP keep-alive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection): so if a single TCP connection is used to download resources, I don't have to worry about how many connections are opened since HTTP 1.1 connections are kept alive by default. I should just check if it is using HTTP 1.0, if so look for `Connection: keep-alive` header.